# Spring Boot: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException Unknown mappedBy in: , referenced property unknown:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring boot 2.4.1 and Java 11.

I am trying to connect these three classes:

**Billing Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="billing")
public class Billing {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="billing_id")
private int billingId;

@Column(name="billing_cycle")
private int billingCycle;

@Column(name="billing_month")
private String billingMonth;

@Column(name="amount")
private double amount;

@Column(name="start_date")
private LocalDate startDate;

@Column(name="end_date")
private LocalDate endDate;

@Column(name="last_edited")
private String lastEdited;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="account_id")
private Account accountId;
//Getters and setters here
}
```

**Account class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="account_id")
private int accountId;

@Column(name="account_name")
private String accountName;

@Column(name="date_created")
private LocalDateTime dateCreated;

@Column(name="is_active")
private String isActive;

@Column(name="last_edited")
private String lastEdited;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
private Customer customerId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountId", cascade={CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.REFRESH})
private Set<Billing> billing = new HashSet<>();

//Getters and setters here
}
```

**Customer Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private int customerId;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@Column(name = "date_created")
private LocalDateTime dateCreated;

@Column(name = "last_edited")
private String lastEdited;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "customerId",targetEntity = Account.class, cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.REFRESH })
private Set<Account> account = new HashSet<>();
```

**Exception**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.accenture.bars.entity.Customer.account, referenced property unknown: java.util.Set.customerId
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.accenture.bars.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.accenture.bars.entity.Customer.account, referenced property unknown: java.util.Set.customerId
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1693) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1661) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the mapping? I am not sure where I went wrong since `accountId` property exists in the `Billing` class. I tried renaming it to just `account` to see if there was just some reference confusion in the code but I still got the same exception.

Comment: Post your customer class also

Comment: @MaxExplode I added it

Comment: Customer and Account have a OneToOne relationship as im seeing, please remove the Set type from Customer

Comment: @MaxExplode I adjusted it to have a ManyToOne and OneToMany and that fixed it. Thank you!